# Print nothing instead of nil

Tags: swift

I created a view that shows the users location on a map and displays the users location in two labels in the view. Its not always there is a subThoroughfare, so "nil" is printed in in the labels. What can I do to just print in nothing instead of "nil" in the label?
Thanks for your help

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class Kart: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myMap: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()



@IBOutlet var adress: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var adress2: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Feil")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)



    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error)

        } else {
            if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks?[0] as! CLPlacemark) {

                var subThoroughfare:String = ""

                if (p.subThoroughfare != nil) {
                    subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare

                }

                self.adress.text = "\(p.thoroughfare) \(p.subThoroughfare)"
                self.adress2.text = " \(p.postalCode) \(p.subLocality)"

            }

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Try using `p.subThoroughfare ? p.subThoroughfare : "Nothing"`

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but where do I put that code?

Comment: Don't mind, I just tried it in a playground and it doesn't work while used in strings

Comment: @ZeMoon you could use 
   var subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare != nil ? p.subThoroughfare : "Nothing"
but my answer, using ?? (nil coalescing operator) is a shorthand way of writing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.adress.text = "\(p.thoroughfare) \(p.subThoroughfare)"
```

uses p.subThoroughfare instead of subThoroughfare. Also, you can use the nil coalescing operator for this (??)

```
var subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare ?? ""
```

will evaluate to p.subThoroughfare if it is not nil, otherwise it will evaluate to ""

so:

```
var subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare ?? "" 
self.adress.text = "\(p.thoroughfare) \(subThoroughfare)"
self.adress2.text = " \(p.postalCode) \(p.subLocality)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line that prints subThoroughfare into your if statement:

```
if (p.subThoroughfare != nil) {
                subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare
                self.adress.text = "\(p.thoroughfare) \(p.subThoroughfare)"
            }

else
    self.adress.text = "\(p.thoroughfare)"
```

Also: It doesn't look like you're using that subThoroughfare variable.